# For loop in recursive function?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion

When the for loop runs, why does it print all permutations of ABC instead of all 'A's?

```
def perm(l, n, str_a):
    if len(str_a) == n:
        print str_a
    else:
        for c in l:
            perm(l, n, str_a+c)


perm("ABC", 3, "")
```

Prints:

```
AAA AAB AAC ABA ABB ABC ACA ACB ACC BAA BAB BAC BBA BBB BBC BCA BCB...
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output?

Comment: Wow... please be clearer next time. It took me 5 minutes to understand what you are asking. You have a code that works, but you can't understand why. Please state this clearly next time.

Comment: I'm sorry you found my question ambiguous.  I have update for output as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you call `perm("ABC", 3, "")`, the `else` clause is executed (because `len("") != 3`).
2. This result in the calls `perm("ABC", 3, "A")`, `perm("ABC", 3, "B")` and `perm("ABC", 3, "C")`. Let's see what happens with the first one:
3. Again, the `else` is executed, resulting in the function calls `perm("ABC", 3, "AA")`, `perm("ABC", 3, "AB")` and `perm("ABC", 3, "AC")`.
4. The same thing happens with  the other function calls from step 2 (you get the idea).
5. Let's look at `perm("ABC", 3, "AA")`: When called, the `else` is executed yet again --> `perm("ABC", 3, "AAA")`, `perm("ABC", 3, "AAB")` and `perm("ABC", 3, "AAC")`.
6. In these calls, the expression `len(str_a)` finally is `== 3`, which means that `str_a` will be printed.
7. And so on, until `CCC`.

Comment: This has really cleared this up for me.  I understand now how the permutations are being generated.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It does not keep printing 'A's, because, after 3 recursions, it will have formed the string "AAA".
Then, the line `print str_a` will be executed, as the condition `len(str_a) == n` will be verified.

After that, the execution will go back to the callee function, which was inside the `c` loop. `c` had value "A". At the following iteration, `c` will get value "B", and `perm("ABC", 3, "AAB")` will be invoked, printing "AAB", and so on.

Maybe the recursion graph could clearen things up (it's incomplete, because it's big)[image: Recursion graph (incomplete)]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the graph was extremely useful.  I'll try to make my question clearer in future.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you are trying to do, but maybe a little bit of debug output would help you figure it out. Try this:

```
def perm(iter, l, n, str_a):
    print "starting iteration {0}: l='{1}', n='{2}', str_a='{3}'".format(
        iter, l, n, str_a)
    if len(str_a) == n:
        print str_a
    else:
       for c in l:
           perm(iter+1, l, n, str_a+c)

perm(1, "ABC", 3, "")
```